# Implement FFDShow in .net

Tags: c#, .net, ffdshow, dolby

I want to use FFDShow to upscale a stereo stream from one of the audio inputs on my computer using the PLII implementation.

I can't seem to find any examples on how to use FFDShow with .net anywhere.

I found this post from a guy that created a couple of projects, I written him but he haven't been online since 2011, do anyone have these projects or know how to use FFDShow with .Net.
http://forum.doom9.net/showthread.php?p=1270421#post1270421

Thanks

Comment: ffdshow is abandonware - if you want to use Dolby ProLogic then your hardware should have come with a driver and other software to enable you to do that without needing a third-party codec-pack...

Comment: Where can I read about this?

Comment: Well, exactly what source-material, hardware/interconnects are you using?

Comment: I want to do this on a VM with a input from an application like Voicemeeter/Virtual Audio Cable or something like that. The source will properly be Dante Via running on the host machine and sending the signal to the input on the VM